# Sending email through Gmail with mailx gives error "Send options without primary recipient specified"

Tags: bash, email, gmail, mailx

I am trying to send an email with a Bash script with my Gmail account using `mailx`. I have the following code in the script:

```
mailx -v -s "$SUBJECT"  
-S smtp-use-starttls  
-S ssl-verify=ignore  
-S smtp-auth=login  
-S smtp=smtp://smtp.gmail.com/587  
-S from="$SENDER"  
-S smtp-auth-user="$SENDER"  
-S smtp-auth-password="$PASSWORD"  
$RECEIVER
```

This gives me the error `Send options without primary recipient specified`. I thought the last line was the primary recipient. How can I send this email?

Comment: The last line is ineded the primary recipient - unless the variable happens to be empty, or contain whitespace, in which case things get more complicated. Where is `$RECEIVER` set in the script? (Ideally provide the entire script, except your password)

Comment: The last _argument_ is the primary recipient. Do you have a backslash (``\``) at the end of every line but the last?

Answer (score 3):

I just had a similar problem.

In my case it was  due to a newline at the end of an email list causing `mailx` to receive an empty address.